# sending variable through ajax post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm doing some ajax stuff which triggers on a click event, the link has a couple of values and variables.

The link in question looks like this:

```
<?php $link_url = esc_url(wp_nonce_url( site_url('?my_page=ajax-processor&action=dynamic_date_loop&my_date='.$date), 
"dynamic_date_loop_nonce") ); ?>
```

**The $date variable above holds a string like "2013-09".**

I process this link and extract the values here:

```
var url = wpAjax.unserialize(element.attr('href'));
var s = {};
s.data = $.extend(s.data, { action: url.action, _ajax_nonce: url._wpnonce });
```

I understand the syntax for this goes something like `var1:value1` but here my value is a variable, so in this context do I just add `my_date: url.$date` ? This just doesn't look right to me.

Comment: You won't have access to your PHP variable `$date` when you're executing your javascript code. You'll have to extract it from the query string you've assembled and placed in the javascript variable `url`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
s.data = $.extend(s.data, {
    action: url.action,
    _ajax_nonce: url._wpnonce,
    my_date: url.my_date 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so does url.my_date know that I mean, get the value that is inside the php variable $date?

Comment: No, it's getting it from the `my_date=XXX` parameter in the URL, just like `url.action` gets the `action=dynamic_date_loop` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

No you need to store the value in `javascript` variable

```
var a = '<?php echo $date; ?>';
```

Now `variable a` contains the value of `$date`. Now you can do whatever you want with a.
Check it by alerting `alert(a);`

Comment: okay, but this code takes place in a javascript file and link inside separate webpage. If I echo the php variable into a javascript variable that variable still needs to go into the link.